# Having trouble getting django heroku to run properly. How do I resolve error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"?

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework

I have previously ran this app on Heroku without issues. But it had been around 6 months since I deployed and I also switched computers from a Linux to a Windows machine.

Now when I deploy, the deployment is successful but the service does not work. When I check the logs the error is:
code=H14 desc="No web processes running"

I have not changed the Procfile or the requirements.txt since it had been working

requirements.txt:

```
django
gunicorn
django-heroku
requests
djangorestframework
django-cors-headers
flask-sslify
```

Procfile:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn findtheirgifts.wsgi --log-file -

wsgi.py

"""
WSGI config for findtheirgifts project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "findtheirgifts.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have tried some suggestions from similar threads
heroku ps:restart
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku ps:scale web=1

None of which seemed to change anything. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in initialized the heroku git file in a different directory than I had previously. Causing the app to not find the Procfile.

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, your app doesn't have any web process running.
You can see all running processes from the CLI with the following command:

```
heroku ps -a <your app name>
```

And scale your web process to 1 with the following:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 -a <your app name>
```

Which will start one instance of your app.
See the [Heroku Scaling Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling).